# How can I hang a viola de gamba on the wall?

Tags: storage, viola-da-gamba

Will a standard guitar hangar work? And is there a measurement or way to tell if a particular hangar will work for a particular instrument?

Is this a safe way to store my instrument?

I’ve provided a picture for scale.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a fully informed answer, but I'll take a shot at a few:

- Many guitar hangers won't work because their "fork" relies on the headstock being wider than the neck. For this instrument, as well as many violins/violas/cellos, the pegbox is the same width as the neck, so it would be the pegs bearing the weight, which maybe isn't a great idea (and might cause it to hang crooked too). Also, a gamba is deeper front-to-back than most guitars; you'd have to make sure the fork "sticks out" far enough from the wall.
- I've seen some that are specifically made for string instruments, like this "[String Swing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ICR720E)," in which the instrument is more hung by the heel at the back of the pegbox. It still makes me a bit antsy that it could be bumped and fall.
- Many violin shops, including high-end dealers, hang violins for display. These are often hung by a sort of upside-down "staple" of wire that lets you hook the scroll over it. I've seen them not do this with cellos, though, but stand them in wooden stands. I'm not sure whether there's concern, with the heavier instrument, about strain on the scroll? Or whether it just becomes less practical?
- There's a lot to be said for storing your instrument outside its case—and a lot to be said against it. Right now my daughter's cello is in the middle of the living room, sitting in an [Ingles cello stand](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/InglesVcl--ingles-sa22-adjustable-cello-double-bass-stand). This can be adjusted up so high that she can even keep her endpin out; she can practice just by picking it up. Having your instrument ready-to-hand can make it easier to play spontaneously. But it comes at the cost of keeping it less protected: in particular, you have to make sure that the room temperature and humidity are stable and within safe zones for the instrument. It's a lot easier to control humidity inside a case, and if the room temperature changes, the temp inside the case changes more gradually. The instrument is also more vulnerable to accidents on a stand, if someone were to walk into it. But if you're satisfied about these concerns, maybe a similar stand could be a good solution. (And useful in concerts, like if you swap between tenor, treble, or bass!)

Bottom line, your instrument is safest in a good case, but there can be benefits to having it out on display if you are okay with the precautions.

Comment: With kids or dogs around, I'd be tempted to put it high on a wall, certainly not in the middle of a room, no matter what stand it's on. Or, keep the door locked.

Comment: @Tim And lol, it's me who's most often running around chasing the dog through the house for fun. But yeah, it's well out of the way. And yeah, it's for sure a consideration.

Comment: A collision would make a baroque-n viola de gamba

Comment: Leaving your instrument out will subject your instrument to dust and light, which is not the best care for good varnish. So if the instrument is of at least decent quality you should think about storing it in a dark, dust-free environment. Prolonged exposure to light will make the varnish harder, eventually leading to cracks.